# Iterating over built-in atributes of foo.py module. Got an error

Tags: python, methods, built-in

I'm doing a loop: "for atribute in dir(foo):"

however i can not use 'atribute' variable as it were built-in atributes of foo. Why is that?

When

```
print(__name__)         # <class 'str'>
```

and

```
for atribute in dir(foo):
   print(atribute)        # is <class 'str'> too
```

...so why I get an error as below?

```
import foo

for atribute in dir(foo):
    print(foo.atribute)

#AttributeError: module 'foo' has no attribute 'atribute'
```

Comment: What you expect ˋfoo.methodˋ to do outside your loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method from you `for` statement, differs from the method of `foo`. Imagine having a list; when you iterate over it with the variable `x` you obviously can't do `list.x`. In some way or another, you are doing exactly this. A way to get an attribute from a string is the `getattr` function. In your case it would be used like so:

```
import foo

for method in dir(foo):
    print(getattr(foo, method))
```

[Here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/getattr) is a usefull link about this function.

Answer (score 1):

When you're trying to print `foo.method`, you are trying to lookup a `method` attribute of the `foo` object. That name is unrelated to the `method` variable you already have in your local namespace. To lookup an attribute who's name is in the `method` variable, use `getattr`:

```
for method in dir(foo):
    print(getattr(foo, method))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop, `method` is a `name` which refers to different object on each iteration.

When you do `foo.method`, you're trying to get an attribute of module `foo` with literal name `method`, which is not the name `method` that you're using in the loop. If you use a different attribute e.g. `foo.bar`, it would be more clear to you.

Now, presumably you want to get the attribute that the loop variable `method` refers to, if so you need `getattr` which gets attribute values from string attribute names.

`dir` returns the attributes as a *list of strings*, so on each iteration you get the value of the attribute string object referred by the name `method`:

```
for method in dir(foo):
    print(getattr(foo, method))
```